# JavaScript filtering cells for each table columns

Tags: javascript

I have a table with `n` rows by `m` columns. My goal is to put multiple filtering boxes so I can filter multiple columns in separated filtering boxes. I have JavaScript like this:

```
function (document) {
    'use strict';
        var MyTableFilter = (function (Arr) {
            var _input;
            function _onInputEvent(e) {
                _input = e.target;
                var tables = document.getElementsByClassName(_input.getAttribute('data-table'));
                Arr.forEach.call(tables, function (table) {
                    Arr.forEach.call(table.tBodies, function (tbody) {
                        Arr.forEach.call(tbody.rows, _filter);
                    });
                });
            }
            function _filter(row) {    
                var input0Value = document.getElementById('input0').value;
                var input1Value = document.getElementById('input1').value;
                var text = row.textContent.toLowerCase(), val = _input.value.toLowerCase();
                var tdsArray = row.children;
                var td0Content = tdsArray[0].textContent;
                var td1Content = tdsArray[1].textContent;
                function isDisplayRow() {
                    return td0Content.indexOf(input0Value) !== -1 &&
                            td1Content.indexOf(input1Value) !== -1
                }
                row.style.display = isDisplayRow() ? 'table-row' : 'none';
            }
            return {
                init: function () {
                    var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('my-table-filter');
                    Arr.forEach.call(inputs, function (input) {
                        input.oninput = _onInputEvent;
                    });
                }
            };
        })(Array.prototype);

        document.addEventListener('readystatechange', function () {
            if (document.readyState === 'complete') {
                MyTableFilter.init();
            }
        });

  })(document);
```

I have input `id`/`class` in form like this:

```
<input type="search" id="input0" class="my-table-filter" data-table="order-table" placeholder="Firstname"/>
<input type="search" id="input1" class="my-table-filter" data-table="order-table" placeholder="Lastname"/>
```

However, when I run the program, the result is not what I expected. So for example, I have John Smith, Henry Wills in the table. If I type 'H'; in first name search box and 'S' in last name search box, I should only get 'JOHN SMITH'. However, I am getting 'HENRY WILLS' as well because 'HENRY' has 'N' and 'WILLS' has 'S'. If I type out the whole words of 'JOHN SMITH', it works OK.

Also, how do I turn off case sensitive for the input text?
I am very new to JavaScript. Any suggestion would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue comes from your filter function, which does a substring search. You can modify it to a prefix search easily:

```
function isDisplayRow() {
    return td0Content.indexOf(input0Value) === 0 &&
        td1Content.indexOf(input1Value) === 0
}
```

Comment: Thank you @clemens! This works perfectly! One more thing, if my 3rd and 4th columns are person's  'address_1' and 'address_2'. And I want to add one box for columns 3 and 4 so when I type in address in this box, if it matches string either in column 3 or in column 4, I will have the match?

Comment: @coding: You might use the same approach as for the name, but you have to connect the clauses for the address fields with || (or) and add this or clause in parentheses with and to the others in isDisplayRow.

Comment: Thanks! It worked. If I have person first name 'JOHN' and 'JOHNNY', when I type in JOHN, I only want to see JOHN and not JOHNNY. I tried string.match or string.exactMatch, it did not work. Do you have any suggestions? Thanks again!

Comment: @coding: A simple `==` should be enough. But if you want a combination prefix and exact matching (showing only exact matches if  existing) this is too complicate for a comment. ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to search only from the begining of String 
you cuold change indexOf to 
String.prototype.startsWith
or 
td0Content.substring(0, input0Value.length) === input0Value